How to do field Injection for @nestjs/bull/InjectQueue
I have base abstract class which is extended by many sub classes. I need to get queue instance reference in base class but with InjectQueue di I can only use construction based injection. Instead I want to use field injection sothat I don't need to pass it from my sub classes.
import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';

@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseRepository<T> {
// Need to do something like this(field injection)
 @InjectQueue(Jobs.CACHE_INVALIDATE)
  private cacheInvalidateJob: Queue;

// I do not wanna to do constructor injection like below as this is my super class and I don't want to pass queue reference from all of my many sub classes
 protected constructor(readonly model: string, 
                       readonly @InjectQueue(Jobs.CACHE_INVALIDATE) cacheInvalidate) {}

}

I tried doing this:
@InjectQueue(Jobs.CACHE_INVALIDATE)
private cacheInvalidateJob: Queue;

But it gives me
TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
The runtime will invoke the decorator with  2  arguments, but the decorator expects  3 
lib.decorators.legacy.d.ts(22, 94): An argument for  parameterIndex  was not provided.


I fixed it like this:
export class BullQueuesProvider {

constructor(@InjectQueue(Jobs.CACHE_INVALIDATOR) readonly cacheInvalidatorJob: 
Queue) {}
}
export class Module {
providers: [BullQueuesProvider]
}
export abstract class BaseRepository<T> {
@Inject()
 protected readonly queues: BullQueuesProvider;
....
  const cacheInvalidatorQueue:Queue = this.queues.cacheInvalidatorJob;
}

Is there any better approach with best practices for this?
